# Error Codes of Syniverse SMS gateway

Tags: sms-gateway

I am using Syniverse SMS gateway to send a notification to users through SMS.
On Searching I came across error codes like

404 - ACCOUNT OR USER DOES NOT EXIST   500 - ERROR  502 - PIN IN DO NOT CALL DATABASE  503 - INSUFFICIENT BALANCE  504 - DATABASE ERROR

which are returned by the SMS gateway in general incase of failure. 
But I want to know what are the error codes that are supported by the Syniverse gateway. Also it would be really helpful if you can share the error handling mechanism in Syniverse gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The different *Error codes* are:-

- 200 - OK
- 404 - ACCOUNT OR USER DOES NOT EXIST
- 502 - PIN IN DO NOT CALL DATABASE
- 503 - INSUFFICIENT BALANCE
- 504 - DATABASE ERROR
- 505 - USER NOT FOUND OR WRONG PASSWORD
- 506 - ACCOUNT NOT ACTIVE
- 507 - DATABASE ERROR
- 508 - DATABASE ERROR
- 510 - INVALID USERNAME
- 511 - INVALID TXT
- 512 - INVALID PASSWORD
- 513 - INVALID PIN
- 520 - ERROR PARSING XML

All values from 0 - 399 (inclusive) mean success, all other values mean failure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. These are returned by SMS gateways in general. Are these supported by syniverse? or is there any syniverse specific error codes?